# Google Play Services allow access - Custom message

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, google-fit

I've set up my app to integrate with Google Fit in order to get user's step data. When they open the app, they are prompted with this message:

[image]

My question is: **Can I have custom text prompted to the user?**

I'd like to say something like, "Sign in to your Google Account in order to sync your Google Fit data with our app." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the authorization prompt, but assuming you are using [react-native-google-fit](https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit), you can probably show your own modal asking if the user wants to connect, and only if the user agrees, call:

```
GoogleFit.authorizeFit();
```

which will show google prompt